# how to Merge results of two different entities in C#?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

```
IQueryable<v_Search> query = from pd in context.v_Search select pd;
IQueryable<t_HistoricAccountImport> xschistory  = from pd in context.t_HistoricAccountImport select pd;

query = query.Where(x => names.Any(y => x.insured_name.Contains(y)));
xschistory = xschistory.Where(xsc => names.Any(y => xsc.insured_name.Contains(y)));
```

Both entities are present in same context

Now when i try below code to combine two results ,using union or concat ,which doesnt happen.

Try 1)

```
var results = query.concat(xschistory); //Caused error
var result1 = query.union(xschistory); //this also throws error
```

I also tried to select columns from the entity with similar datatype and values and tried to merge,

Try 2)

```
    var res1 = query.ToList().Select
                        (x => new 
                        { x.insured_name ,
                          x.ReferenceNum
                        });
    var res2 = xschistory.ToList().Select
                        (y=> new 
                        {
                            y.insured_name,
                            y.program_id
                        });

 var finalResults = res1.Union(res2); //Still got Error
```

is there anyway to accomplish this ?

Comment: I believe they need to have the same number of columns.

Comment: @ Martin ,Error was IQueryable<v_Search> does not contain definition for union and the best extension method overload 'System.linq.parellelEnumerable.Union<TSource>'(System.linq.parellelquery<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource) has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

One of the things you can do is bind them to

```
 List<v_search> a; List<t_HistoricAccountImport> b;
```

and then

```
var together = a.Cast<object>().Concat(b.Cast<object>()).ToList();//cast preferably to something they both inherit from, and is not 'object'.
```

You cannot a.concat(b) now because the objects are not of the same type.